# Instances on Points not working correctly

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to add sugar to my churro, so i created differently shaped cubes, added them so a collection, and used them as instances for the Instance on Points Node. However, when i try to increase the density, instead of sticking to the churro, a giant cube just appears from out of nowhere. There is no gradiant or anything, the cube just pops up. I mean, i don't even know what to google to try and figure out what the problem here is.

[image: Low density]

[image: giant cubes appears when i go above 100 density more or less.]

Here is the file in case you want to take a look, thanks a bunch!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zwN5oTe22kGGo3VxmtgQDtS27g2ioMW8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply scale for cubes. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → Apply scale)